# How do you invoke a bean method from Javascript in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

How do you invoke a bean method from Javascript in PrimeFaces?

I have the following menuItem:

```
<p:menuitem id="toggleAlarms" icon="ui-icon-cancel" rendered="#{navigationBean.admin}" value="Cancel Alert" update=":alarmMessages"  action="#{alarmsBean.toggleAlertOff()}"/>
```

When I click on that item in the UI the method gets called.

But when I have this element:

```
<p:messages id="alarmMessages">
    <script>
    jQuery('#alarmMessages').effect("pulsate", {times:5}, 1000 );
    jQuery('#alarmMessages').show();
    $('#alarmMessages').click(function() {
        jQuery('#toggleAlarms').click();
        alert('fool');
    })
    </script>
</p:messages>
```

If I click on the messages object on the UI, I can see the alert message with fool in it.

However, I never see the toggleAlarms.click() method invoke the alarmsBean.toggleAlertOff() call.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: When you "View Source" on the rendered page, what is the id of the messages component? Is it "toggleAlarms" or is it something else e.g. "form:toggleAlarms"? It is possible that you are not passing the correct component id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

any chance that `#{navigationBean.admin}` returns `false` ?

cause if so you wont be able to find it in the DOM... (maybe better use `style=display:none`)

also , your selector might be wrong if the menuitem is inside form try `jQuery('#someFormID\\:toggleAlarms').click();` do *view source* on your web page to see the right id of the menuitem

finally try the same with commandButton instead (not sure that menuitem will respond as expected to `.click()`)

**Update**

in order to check if your jquery selector is right use `alert($('#toggleAlarms').length)` instead of `alert('fool');`

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for your response.  admin is always true so far.

Comment: OK, it works like a charm after modifying it based on the info. you provided.  Thanks a lot!  Here is what I did:

Modified menuitem:

    <p:menuitem id="toggleAlarms" icon="ui-icon-cancel" style="display:none;" value="Cancel Alert" update=":alarmMessages" action="#{alarmsBean.toggleAlertOff()}"/>

And this:

    jQuery('#alarmMessages').effect("pulsate", {times:5}, 1000 );
    jQuery('#alarmMessages').show();
    $('#alarmMessages').click(function() {
        jQuery('#menuF\\:toggleAlarms').click();
    })